# Oracle: Create a View with Auto Increment id column

Tags: oracle, view, plsql, oracle11g

I have created a `view` that fills data from different tables. I used `10 select statements` and   combine the results of those select statements using `UNION ALL`.

I want to add `primary key column` to my view. because I have to create `XML` file using data in this `view`. so I need a `primary key column` for some process in my `XML` building application.

I have add `rownum` to all my select statements. But it returned duplicate ids. because `rownum` in each select statements start from 1.

Then I have created a sequence and tried use `nextval` . But I can't use sequence because my select statements has `group by` and `order by`.

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do a select over the union, for example:

```
SELECT rownum(),*
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableB)
```

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT rownum, t.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT * FROM tableB) t
```

Comment: I got an error. `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: did you put the asterisk? you should put your column names, I just put it as an example.

Comment: i put column names. it's worked without `rownum()`. when add `rownum()`, getting error.

Comment: @Bishan, these are small syntax errors, try- `select rownum, t.* from (select ... union all select ...) t`

Comment: @A.B.Cade Will the rownum change for the existing records if new records are added?

Comment: @XiaoPeng-BuilderofZenUML - the rownum simply reflects the query results each time you query the view. It doesn't remember anything from one execution to another, if that's what you were asking.