# How to create id with AUTO_INCREMENT on a view in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

can any one help to create a AUTO_INCREMENT column on a view in oracle 11g.

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to accomplish.  A view doesn't persist data, it's just a stored query.  Do you want to create a persistent autoincrementing column in an underlying table?  A non-persistent (and thus potentially variable over time) increasing numeric column in a view?  Something else?

Comment: Use [ROWNUM](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255)

Comment: Rownum is changing when data is changing.So its not consistent

Comment: Justin, i have a view which converts coma separated values from a column from parent table to rows.So the id in the original table is not a unique id now in the view it will repeat for coma separated values.So i want to create a new ID in view.

Comment: As @JustinCave mentioned above, a view is just a stored query. Without persisting a value into an underlying table, you can't really guarantee that it won't change over time as new data comes in and fits into the middle of the sort.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229056/oracle-create-a-view-with-auto-increment-id-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not possible to return a single unique identity column for a view whose underlying data does not have any single unique identifier, it is possible to return composite values that uniquely identify the data.  For example given a table of CSV Data with a unique ID on each row:

```
create table sample (id number primary key, csv varchar2(4000));
```

where the CSV column contains a string of comma separated values:

```
insert into sample 
select 1, 'a' from dual union all
select 2, 'b,c' from dual union all
select 3, 'd,"e",f' from dual union all
select 4, ',h,' from dual union all
select 5, 'j,"",l' from dual union all
select 6, 'm,,o' from dual;
```

The following query will unpivot the csv data and the composite values (`ID`, `SEQ`) will uniquely identify each `VAL`ue, The `ID` column idetifies the record the data came from, and `SEQ` uniquely identifies the position in the CSV:

```
WITH pvt(id, seq, csv, val, nxt) as (
SELECT id  -- Parse out individual list items
     , 1   -- separated by commas and 
     , csv -- optionally enclosed by quotes
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(csv,'(["]?)([^,]*)\1',1,1,null,2)
     , REGEXP_INSTR(csv, ',', 1, 1)
FROM sample
UNION ALL
SELECT id
     , seq+1
     , csv
     , REGEXP_SUBSTR(csv,'(["]?)([^,]*)\1',nxt+1,1,null,2)
     , REGEXP_INSTR(csv, ',', nxt+1, 1)
FROM pvt
 where nxt > 0
)
select * from pvt order by id, seq;

        ID        SEQ CSV        VAL               NXT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1 a          a                   0

         2          1 b,c        b                   2
         2          2 b,c        c                   0

         3          1 d,"e",f    d                   2
         3          2 d,"e",f    e                   6
         3          3 d,"e",f    f                   0

         4          1 ,h,        [NULL]              1
         4          2 ,h,        h                   3
         4          3 ,h,        [NULL]              0

         5          1 j,"",l     j                   2
         5          2 j,"",l     [NULL]              5
         5          3 j,"",l     l                   0

         6          1 m,,o       m                   2
         6          2 m,,o       [NULL]              3
         6          3 m,,o       o                   0


15 rows selected.
```