# Create persistent and unique id for a view, even data in view is changed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Based on this question: [Oracle: Create a View with Auto Increment id column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229056/oracle-create-a-view-with-auto-increment-id-column)

Say I have the following data

```
-- table
CREATE TABLE internal_subject
( 
  id number(10) NOT NULL,
  sub_name varchar2(400) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE external_subject
( 
  id number(10) NOT NULL,
  sub_name varchar2(400) NOT NULL
);


-- data
INSERT INTO external_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(1, 'A');

INSERT INTO external_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(2, 'B');


INSERT INTO internal_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(1, 'C');

INSERT INTO internal_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(2, 'D');



-- Create a view 
SELECT 
  rownum, 
  t.sub_name
FROM 
(
  select
    ext_sub.sub_name as sub_name
  from
    external_subject ext_sub

  UNION ALL  

  select
    ext_sub.sub_name as sub_name
  from
    internal_subject ext_sub
) t
```

The select statement will give 1 A, 2 B, 3 C, 4 D for the view.

Now data in internal_subject and external_subject had changed.

Say 2 new row data (E, F) inserted at the start of internal_subject table

```
Change data
--------------------------------
-- table
CREATE TABLE internal_subject
( 
  id number(10) NOT NULL,
  sub_name varchar2(400) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE external_subject
( 
  id number(10) NOT NULL,
  sub_name varchar2(400) NOT NULL
);


-- data
-- old 1, new 1
INSERT INTO external_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(1, 'E');

-- old 2, new 2
INSERT INTO external_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(2, 'F');

-- old '', new 5
INSERT INTO external_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(1, 'A');

-- old '', new 6
INSERT INTO external_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(2, 'B');


-- old 3, new 3
INSERT INTO internal_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(1, 'C');

-- old 4, new 4
INSERT INTO internal_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(2, 'D');



pull after change
--------
-- Test 
SELECT 
  rownum, 
  t.sub_name
FROM 
(
  select
    ext_sub.sub_name as sub_name
  from
    external_subject ext_sub

  UNION ALL  

  select
    ext_sub.sub_name as sub_name
  from
    internal_subject ext_sub
) t
```

The select gives me 1 E, 2 F, 3 A, 4 B, 5 C 6 D.

Is it a way to generate unique and persistent id for row in a view?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put a unique constraint on the `id` columns?

Comment: `ROWNUM` is assigned to rows after they are fetched and one cannot rely on ROWNUM to give you a specified order. You may use `row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY sub_name )` instead of rownum if you want a desired order of A, B,C,D,E,F. But it is unclear what do you mean by unique and persistent id for row.

Comment: I suppose you could use a hash function (`ora_hash()`, `standard_hash()`) to generate a deterministic ID from the data, if that's what you mean by a unique and persistent id for the row.

Comment: ...but then if the unique ID has to reflect the unique `sub_name` then why not just make `sub_name` the id?

Answer (score 1):

You can try use 
[sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) if it permissible..

and when you insert new row in internal_subject/external_subject you should use this code:

```
INSERT INTO internal_subject
(id, sub_name)
VALUES
(yourSequence.nextval, 'X');

-- Create a view  
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
  select id, sub_name from external_subject
  UNION ALL  
  select id, sub_name from internal_subject
```